# gRPC custom netty event loop group

Tags: java, grpc-java

The gRPC examples for Java are quite basic. Does anyone know of any up-to-date examples that actually inject to the server a custom Netty EventLoopGroup? I'm setting up gRPC for the first time in Java while I've used Netty. The service I have makes multiple backend calls using different libraries built on top of Netty, so I would prefer to manage threadpools myself.